# Is $T^{\prime\prime}$ injective for injective $T\in\mathfrak{L}(E,F)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let $E$, $F$ be Banach spaces and $T:E\longrightarrow F$ be a bounded linear operator. Suppose $T$ is injective, is $T^{\prime\prime}$ necessarily injective?

---

**Remark.** My attempts at proving this were to prove the results

> **Claim 1.** $S$ injective $\Rightarrow$ $S'$ has norm-dense image, for all operators, $S$, between Banach spaces.

**Claim 2.** $S$ has norm-dense image $\Rightarrow$ $S'$ injective.

from which the above easily follows. However Claim 1 seems to be invalid. Instead, I only know that

**Claim 1´.** $S$ injective $\Rightarrow$ $S'$ has weak*-dense image

and this result is useless here, unless

> **Claim 2´.** $S'$ has weak*-dense image $\Rightarrow$ $S''$ injective.

holds true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $T:\ell^1\to \ell^1$ which sends a sequence $(a_n)$ to the sequence $(a_n/n)$.  The dual map is then $T':\ell^\infty\to\ell^\infty$ which again sends a sequence $(a_n)$ to $(a_n/n)$.  However, the image of $T'$ is not norm-dense, since every sequence in the image of $S'$ converges to $0$.  Thus the double dual $T''$ is not injective.

Comment: Right toe! This raises the question of what non-zero functionals in $\ell_\infty^*$ are annihilated by $T''$; the answer would be functionals that live out in $N=\infty$ land, like a Banach limit.

Comment: Or in slightly less silly language: Say $K$ is the maximal ideal space of $\ell_\infty$. Then $\ell_\infty\sim C(K)$, so a bounded linear functional on $\ell_\infty$ "is" a measure on $K$. And $K$ is a compactification of $\Bbb N$; the functionals annihilated by $T''$ are the measures that vanish on $\Bbb N$.

Comment: I agree with your comments, @DavidC.Ullrich.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey I can see that it is straightforward to prove that $\mathrm{ran}(T')$ norm-dense $\Leftrightarrow$ $T''$ injective, so your argument holds. Thanks! (although I am thoroughly disappointed, that it’s not true!)